# How do I grab a jpeg from a layer and open it in it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export

How do I grab a jpeg from a layer and open it in its own PSD document, so that I can crop and save how I want?  In the attached image, I would like to have the jpeg in the highlighted layer (without the clipping mask) in its own document so that I can edit it as need be.[image]

Answer (score 9):

#### If you want to keep the layer linked to your current document:

Use [Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html). Right click your layer and click *Convert to Smart Object*. Double clicking the Smart Object layer will open the image in a new tab for you to edit and automatically update the layer in the original file.

#### If you actually want to save it to a new document separate from the original:

With your layer selected, right click the layer or click the dropdown of the layers panel and select *Duplicate Layer...*

[image]

In the *Duplicate Layer* dialog select *New* under 'Document':

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by a second

Comment: I know, I spotted your comments just as I was posting! :p

Comment: No prob, it happens

Comment: I almost didn't post but I'd spent all that time putting those lovely circles on my screenshots already!

Comment: I'm on mobile atm so I couldn't do screenshots anyway.

Comment: -1: those circles are not hand drawn in MS Paint

Comment: Just to add a further method to this, you can create a `New Document` move back to the original and drag the layer onto the new canvas. It works, but it's more clunky than yours.

Answer (score 3):

1. Method 1: Smart object

Right-click the layer and choose 'Convert to smart object'. Now double click the layer and it will open in a new doc. Any edits you make and save will be visible in your original doc.

2. Method 2: Duplicate

Right-click the layer and choose 'Duplicate...'. In the dialogue box that appears choose 'New document'. Voila.

PS: doing this from memory but I think it's right.